# Customize UIMuenuitem title

Tags: iphone, uimenucontroller

I am using the table to display a list of members and when I click a cell in the table I am creating some custom menu items and showing the menu by customizing the cellview class. Now we have total 6 menu items and some of them are long in length, is there any way I can wrap the menu title so that we have enough space to display all the menu items?. While creating the menu item i tried to give the "\n" in the title but no use.

Also I would like to group the menu items so for this i will like to show 3 of them in different color. can we set the text color to the menu item so that 3 of them are in one color and other 3 are in different.

Please let me know if have any solution of the above two tasks.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know both are not possible. You might want to look into creating your own menu code. Which is not terribly difficult. If you are on iOS 4 then just create a long tap gesture recognizer and then show a transparent view with graphics of your menu. This view can contain simple transparent buttons. It is not standard at all but very doable.